# What does the “Word Separator for URL Titles” setting alter

Tags: path, site-preferences

I would like future entries on my site to automatically create the URL titles with dashes-as-separators instead_of_the_default_underscores. I found the setting in Admin > Channel Administration > Global Preferences > Word Separator for URL Titles. There’s a simple switch that you can toggle between underscores and dashes.

Now before I change this, I’m wondering about what this will affect. Will it only alter auto-generated URL titles for entries created within the control panel? Will it alter any behaviour of file paths on the server?

I found [this](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html) article on EllisLab’s docs that says:

> When creating an entry in the PUBLISH page, if you do not manually
>   enter a “URL Title” then the system will automatically create one
>   based on the entry Title. This preference determines whether
>   underscore characters (_) or dashes (-) should be used when
>   automatically creating the URL Title.

Basically what I’m wondering, is, how can I confirm (prove) that nothing else will be altered before changing this setting?

Answer (score 3):

Only new entries will use the new separator.

Old entries will be left using the "original" separator they were created with.

If you delete the url title and submit the entry. EE will then re-make the url title field using the separator chosen in the setting. I have found no other place anywhere that relies upon the url titles setting.

I tested this on EE 2.9.0

Comment: This will also effect new categories url titles

Answer (score 0):

Its perfectly safe to alter it without affecting anything else than new entries.

All it basically sets is if you add an entry with a title of "my new entry" it converts the spaces to what you set it to, either `- or _`.